# MongoDB query: Find multiple first matching document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection with the following schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  company: ObjectId,
  endTime: date string
}
```

There will be multiple documents for the same `company`.
Few example docs:

```
{_id: 1, company: companyA, endTime: Jan 1,2022}
{_id: 2, company: companyB, endTime: Feb 11,2022}
{_id: 3, company: companyA, endTime: Jan 3,2022}
{_id: 4, company: companyB, endTime: Jan 4,2022}
{_id: 5, company: companyA, endTime: Feb 21,2022}
{_id: 5, company: companyB, endTime: Jan 1,2022}
```

Now I want to get the first document per company sorted by endTime (desc). I tried with `aggregate` but was not able to accomplish it.

Result for above docs:

```
{_id: 5, company: companyA, endTime: Feb 21,2022}
{_id: 2, company: companyB, endTime: Feb 11,2022}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$sort` - Sort by `endTime` DESC.
2. `$group` - Group by `company` and take first document (`$first`) as `data` field.
3. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with `data`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      endTime: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$company",
      data: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$data"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nBNAo5ELLTx)

Comment: Awesome. Works as expected! Thanks a lot